# What happened to the old files if we mount a drive to the directory?

Tags: mount

```
mkdir /home
```

then we mount something on `/home`.

Say `/home` already contains files.

What happen to the old files after a new drive is mounted to that directory?

Answer (score 6):

The mount will hide any existing files in the directory used as a mountpoint. Nothing happens to the files themselves.

If you want to access the hidden files without unmounting `/home`, you can bind mount the underlying directory at another mountpoint:

```
$ mount --bind / /mnt
```

Now `/mnt/home/` contains the files hidden by the `/home` mount.

Comment: So ideally the directory for  mounting should be empty?

Comment: Typically the mountpoint is empty prior to the mount, but it doesn't really matter unless you need to access any files that would be hidden by the mount. Keep in mind that the the disk space used by the hidden files is still reported by `df` (which accesses the used block counts from the file system), but wouldn't show up in `du` output (as `du` wouldn't be able to access the files to get their size).

Answer (score 1):

File stays there. Nothing happens to them. It is just hidden beneath the new layer.

But if you are looking for solution to see both file

> a. directory /home content
>
> b. mountpoint /home content

at the same time then you need to study `aufs`

Comment: While there are a number of [unioning](http://lwn.net/Articles/324291/) [file system](http://lwn.net/Articles/325369/) [implementations](http://lwn.net/Articles/327738/) for Linux, including [UnionFS](http://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/project-unionfs.html), [aufs](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/), [Union mounts](http://valerieaurora.org/union/) and [overlayfs](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/mszeredi/vfs.git/), [currently none is included in the mainline kernel](http://lwn.net/Articles/447650/).