# How to view files hidden by a mount on Debian 6

Tags: linux, debian, mount, unmounting

I have been trying for a while to view files, hidden by a mount on my device sporting Debian 6, to no avail, and being new to Linux, I am compelled to ask the question: How do you view files hidden by a mount on Debian 6?

I have gone over the many duplicates I came across as I was drafting this question the first 1 or 10 times and the following answers did not help in my case:

1. [Answer to "Access to original contents of mount point"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4428/72977)
2. [Answer to "Where do the files go if you mount a drive to a folder that already contains files?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41337/72977)
3. [Answer to "What happened to the old files if we mount a drive to the directory? [duplicate]"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92936/72977)

I also found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49347/72977), but it was a little intimidating to try that with my limited knowledge of what I am even doing.

I also asked Linux users around me, who all (both) say that it's impossible to see my files without `umount`ing.

So just to make things clear, this is what I am working with:

```
/tmp # mkdir FOO
/tmp # cd FOO/
/tmp/FOO # touch abc
/tmp/FOO # cd
~ # mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/FOO/
~ # ls /tmp/FOO/
bbb
~ # cd /tmp/
/tmp # mkdir BAR
/tmp # cd
~ # mount --bind / /tmp/BAR
~ # cd /tmp/BAR/
/tmp/BAR # ls
bin      etc      lib      media    proc     sbin     sys      usr
dev      home     linuxrc  mnt      root     selinux  tmp      var
/tmp/BAR # cd tmp/
/tmp/BAR/tmp # ls
/tmp/BAR/tmp #
```

@John1024:

```
~ # mount | grep /tmp/
/dev/sda1 on /tmp/FOO type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp932,iocharset=cp932,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/root on /tmp/BAR type jffs2 (ro,relatime)
```

What and to where should I `mount --bind` to see the files that were in `/tmp/somefolder`? Could the functionality of the solutions linked above be related to what build of Debian I am using?

Edit: For clarification, these are some of the commands I tried:

```
~ # mount --bind /tmp/somefolder /tmp/anotherfolder
~ # mount --bind / /tmp/anotherfolder
~ # mount --bind /dev/sda1 /tmp/anotherfolder
```

Comment: What error messages are you seeing when you run your mount --bind commands?

Comment: No error messages.

Comment: @AdamJensen That is helpful. What is the output of `mount | grep /tmp`?

Comment: What do you get if you `mount --bind /tmp /tmp/BAR`?

Comment: @Scott Wow, that worked. :) `~ # ls /tmp/BAR/FOO` shows `abc`

Comment: OK, John was the first one to post ***an*** answer. But I was the first to provide *the **correct** answer*; it would be nice if you would at least upvote it.

Comment: @Scott You might have been faster to provide the answer to my question, but he was the first to provide the correct answer _as_ an answer. Nonetheless, I didn't notice your post until now, and sure, it calls for an upvote for the helpful explanation and for using the actual directory names for ultimate clarity. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to see the files, if any, hidden by the `mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/somefolder` command.  Assuming that `/tmp` is part of the `/` filesystem, run:

```
mount --bind / /tmp/anotherfolder
ls /tmp/anotherfolder/tmp/somefolder
```

If `/tmp` is not part of `/` but is a separate filesystem, run:

```
mount --bind /tmp /tmp/anotherfolder
ls /tmp/anotherfolder/somefolder
```

Comment: When I try this, `/tmp/anotherfolder/tmp/somefolder` contains the files of the mounted FS (the usbdisk). I still can't see what has been hidden by mounting.

Comment: I tried this from a couple of locations with visibility of the usbdisk contents varying. From where are you ideally supposed to run these commands?

Comment: @AdamJensen It shouldn't do that.  Would you document in your question _precisely_ what commands you run that result in the directory still being hidden?  Leave nothing to the imagination.

Comment: Ok, here goes nothing.

Comment: How do I know whether `/tmp` is a separate filesystem from `/`? Because that seemed to work for me.

Comment: @AdamJensen running `mount` will show you which filesystems are mounted, and their mountpoints. if `/tmp` is separate to `/` you'll seen an entry for `/tmp`

Comment: @AdamJensen The clue for me was when you ran `ls` in `/tmp/BAR/tmp`.  If `/tmp` was part of `/` then both FOO and BAR should have been visible.  Neither was.

Comment: Top notch! Just used this to access my old disk-borne `/tmp`, which has been superseded by a `tmpfs`, and clear down the defunct old contents. I used `/mnt` since it's meant to be specifically for manual, temporary mounts (after checking _it_ was clear, of course...)

Comment: This doesn't work if it's an overlay[fs] that's layered on top (e.g. on `/`). `mount --bind` is unable to see under that.

Comment: Related Q on the latter issue though: https://superuser.com/questions/1357516/accessing-the-lower-mount-of-an-overlay-root-fs

Answer (score 4):

Since `/tmp` is a separate filesystem,
you want to get an unblemished view of the contents of that filesystem
(without the interference from the `/dev/sda1` filesystem,
which is mounted on the subordinate `/tmp/FOO` mount point),
so you need to do a bind mount on `/tmp`:

```
mount --bind /tmp /tmp/BAR
```

Now `/tmp/BAR` should show you the contents of `/tmp`,
and `/tmp/BAR/FOO` should show you the contents of `/tmp/FOO`,
which had been hidden by the mount on `/tmp/FOO`.